# How can i register classpath files in pig script?

Tags: hadoop, properties, mapreduce, classpath, apache-pig

Is there any way to add/register classpath property files (like eg: database.properties) in the pig script so that my application can read it. Note: Adding in to HADOOP/PIG_CLASSPATH is not working in my distribution.

Answer (score 0):

How are you exactly executing your script and what are you needs? (file in frontend, backend, both,...).

Try packaging the .properties in a .jar and the registering that .jar in your pig script (this if you need .properties to be read in backend).

If you need that .properties in your frontend (executing in grunt) you will have to put your .properties in CLASSPATH.

And in you need it in frontend and backend, do both things told: .jar + CLASSPATH.